# How to update datacontext of a view from altogether different view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to understand if we can update a XView datacontext from ZViewModel?

I have a XView and on load it is bound to its DataContext is bound to its XViewModel.

In ZViewModel I create a new instance of XViewModel and want to update the XView's datacontext with this new XViewModel.

Can I do this? Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: not as far as I know.

Furthermore, it somewhat goes against the principles of MVVM to have a ViewModel "looking up" into a View at all.

If you're trying to radically change some set of data in XViewModel you might look into the [Event Bus](http://chriskoenig.net/2010/07/05/mvvm-light-messaging/) in MVVM Light. It can let one VM subscribe to a message of a certain type and perform some action when it receives that message.

You could, in effect:

1. Have XViewModel register for messages of type T
2. Have ZViewModel pass a message of type T on the EventBus
3. XViewModel will execute some handler when it receives ZViewModels message

The beauty is that neither VM knows about the other. It's completely decoupled via the bus.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is a UserControl this is pretty easy. You can set a binding for the DataContext to a property in your ViewModel. Clicking the button would essentially reset the UserControl to it's default state.

```
<Window
    //usual Window declarations>

   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
      <view:MyView DataContext="{Binding MyViewModelProperty}" />
      <Button Command="{Binding CmdChangeViewModel}"
              Content="Change VM" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel:

```
private IViewModelBase _MyViewModelProperty;
public IViewModelBase MyViewModelProperty
{
   get { return _MyViewModelProperty; }
   set { Set("MyViewModelProperty", ref _MyViewModelProperty, value); }
}

public ICommand CmdChangeViewModel
{
    get
    {
       return new RelayCommand(() =>
       {
          MyViewModelProperty = new MyViewModel();
       });
    }
}
```

If your view is another Window then you'll want to use a [ViewModelLocator](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/working-with-a-simple-viewmodellocator-from-mvvm-lite). I use the one in [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/). Using the same MainViewModel above, clicking a button in your main View would change the DataContext of the other window.

Child Window:

```
<Window
   //usual Window declarations
   DataContext="{Binding Main.MyViewModelProperty, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
```